# Directory disappears in R Studio-server on a GCE VM after I mount a Google Cloud Bucket to it

Tags: r, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I used to be able to mount Google Cloud Bucket to a GCE VM and access my data in it when using R-Studio Server in this VM. I am now using a new laptop (but the VM is still the same) and when I mount the bucket in the very same way I used to, R-Studio Server can no longer find the directory where I mounted it. If I unmount the bucket, R-Studio can again find the directory. I am very puzzled why that is the case. What should I do to fix it?

A few more information:

- My VM is setup for Ubuntu 22.04 and my laptop runs Windows. My previous laptop was running Ubuntu 22.04.
- I am building my data to `/home/my_username/remote/` using  `gcsfuse -implicit-dirs my-bucket /home/my_username/remote/`.
- In the directory `/home/my_username/` there are other directories besides `remote`. I can access and see them all in R-Studio independently if my bucket is mounted or not.
- If the bucket is not mounted, if I type `ls` in the command line when in the `/home/my_username/` directory, the `remote` directories shown in green background and blue letters meaning it is "other-writable directory" while the other directories show in blue letters only, meanning they are just "directory". Once I build the bucket to `remote`, it starts showing in blue letters without the green background, just like the other directories (but then I cannot see/access it anymore on R-Studio). I can still access and see the `remote` directory in the command prompt though. If I `cd` into it, I can see the directories inside my bucket.
- When I run the command `ls -la /home/my_username/remote` after having mounted the bucket I get the following output:

> ```
> total 0
> drwxr-xr-x 1 my_username my_username 0 May 22 05:38 processed_input
> drwxr-xr-x 1 my_username my_username 0 May 22 05:38 processed_input_reproduction
> drwxr-xr-x 1 my_username my_username 0 May 22 05:38 raw_input
> ```

- When I run the command `fdisk -l` (both with the bucket mounted and not mounted) I get the following output:

> ```
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop6: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop7: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop8: Permission denied
> ```

Comment: Show the output from the command `ls -la /home/my_username/remote` after mounting the bucket.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have just edited my question to include the output to this command

Comment: Is that the listing you expect for the bucket? The mount appears to work correctly. Clarify what is missing or what cannot be accessed and the error message.

Comment: @JohnHanley, that`s what I would expect from the mounting. There is no error message. However, I cannot see the `remote` directory in R-Studio Server and I cannot access it there, as I mentioned in my original question. Before, I would do the exact same process and would not have this sort of issue.

Comment: @RobertoAS Can you check the output of `fdisk -l` command and also let us know why you are unmounting the bucket and mounting it again. Have you checked while you are performing an unmount operation whether your R studio server is performing some write operations..? Have you tried changing the mount point name and creating a new mount point and use it in your R studio server..?

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni I have updated my question with the output to `fdisk -l`. I unmounted the bucket just to try to see if the issue persisted. It only happens when the bucket is mounted. If everything was working fine, I would have just mounted the bucket and that is it. R Studio was not performing any writing operations. I tried changing the path where I am mounting, but I get the same issue.